# Historically data search in SQL database

Tags: java, sql, search

I have a use case to search normalized SQL database for given criteria in historical database of more than few million records. Using StoredProcedure to join normalized table is solving the search but performance is very slow.

Is there any alternate where we take the data in to memory and perform search.

Would like to know approach to solve problem.

Comment: Make sure your few million records are indexed the same way as your WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

You could setup Elastic search that will cache frequently executed searchs

Answer (score 0):

Use the **APACHE Module** named **SOLR** that has ability to handle big data with faceted search.
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/